# List items get mixed up after adding new items android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which displays a list of items fetched from the server. I have created a ALertDialog with EditText which takes user input and makes a API call and this user input gets added to the items server. Again the new updated items are displayed in the ListView.

The issue is initailly when the list is displayed it displayes properly. But when the user input is posted, it displayes randomly and not at the end of the list.

Here is my code:-

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Post", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {

                    boolean worked = true;
                    postedString = input1.getText().toString();

                    if(postedString .length()==0 || postedString =="")
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(NewsDetails.this, "Please enter a comment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        input1.findFocus();
                        worked = false;
                    }
                    else if(worked && postedString !="")
                    {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        pd = new ProgressDialog(Details.this);
                        pd.setMessage("Posting..");
                        pd.show();
                        pd.setCancelable(true);

                        Post(postedString );
                    }
                }
    private void Post(String postedString)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String postCommentUrl  = EndPoints.PostURL;

                        new PostComment().execute(postCommentUrl);
                        String getRequestForComments = myurl;
                        new FetchItems().execute(getRequest);

                    }
            })



    private class PostComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {



            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                HttpResponse response =null;
                String resultString = "";
                String myResponseBody = "" ;
                // Creating HTTP client
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Creating HTTP Post
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(params[0]);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(8);
                nameValuePair.add(my params)
                try 
                {
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                    response = httpClient.execute(request);
                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                    {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null)
                        {

                            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                            myResponseBody = convertToString(inputStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return myResponseBody;
            }



    private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<String,String, Void> 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpResponse response =null;
            String resultString = "";
            String myResponseBody = "" ;
            // Creating HTTP client
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Creating HTTP Post
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);


            try 
            {
                response = httpClient.execute(request);
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null)
                    {

                        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                        myResponseBody = convertToString(inputStream);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(myResponseBody);
                            JSONArray mtUsers = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("ListOfComments");
                            for (int i = 0; i < mtUsers.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject menuObject = mtUsers.getJSONObject(i);

                                String authorName= parsed code


                                map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                                map.put(my params)

                                myList.add(map);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Collections.reverse(myList);
                        getList = myList;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
            return null;

        }





        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();

            itemsAdapter = (ListAdapter) new CAdapter(Details.this, getList);

            myList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
            ListViewInScrollViewHeight.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(myList);
            myList.invalidate();
            myList.refreshDrawableState();
            myList.post(new Runnable() 
            {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myList.setSelection(itemsAdapter.getCount()-1);

                }
            });
        }
```

//Adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi=convertView;
    LazyViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.layout.comments_row,null);

        viewHolder = new LazyViewHolder();

        viewHolder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        viewHolder.description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); // artist name
        viewHolder.pubDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (LazyViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    //Set title
    String myTitle =song.get(Details.AUTHORDISPLAYNAME);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myTitle);

    int i = 0;
    while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 40)) != -1) 
    {
        sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
    }

    viewHolder.title.setText(sb.toString());

    //Set description
    String mydescription = song.get(Details.TEXT);


    viewHolder.description.setText(mydescription);

    // Set image
    //   String bitmapUrl = song.get(Home.avatarUrl);

    //Set date
    String myDate = song.get(NewsDetails.DATEUPDATED);

    final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    final String NEW_FORMAT = "HH:mm, MMMM dd, yyyy";

    String newDate ="";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
    try
    {
        Date d = sdf.parse(myDate);
        sdf.applyLocalizedPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
        newDate = sdf.format(d);
        viewHolder.pubDate.setText(newDate);
    } 
    catch (java.text.ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the returned JSONArray? Does it contain the items in the right oder? If no, your problem is how the server-side script queries the database. For example if you are querying a mysql database you may sort the results by id with `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: but initially i get the list in a proper order. its only if i add a new item it gets added somewhere in the middle of the list. if i finish the activity and open again. i get it in a right order again